# How to fix column-gap issue with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

Why is the `column-gap` specification not working in this example? I get what looks like columns that are horizontally justified.

I want the elements in each column to have a maximum width.

```css
#col {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}
#col p {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts -->

<div id="col">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua.
  </p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to remove spacing between columns ?

Comment: yes, I do......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's displayed as block, 
Use `display: inline-block` instead

```css
#col {
  display: inline-block;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}

#col p {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts -->

<div id="col">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

You can also achieve this using `inline-grid`:

```css
#col {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

#col p {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="col">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: side note: usually, column-gap is used to split long paragraph into 2 separate columns with some gap between. There is no need for column gap if you're wrapping each paragraph width `p` tag and adding border around it.

Comment: Thanks! This is just an example, in my real situation I have form elements that I want to split into columns.

Comment: In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png

Answer (score 2):

Removed the gap between two columns as required
To be precise the column-gap:0 is working in your code and you have used `max-width:200px` in your code so the `<p>` gets wrapped within 200px and doesnt reach the end.
Hope this helps.

```css
#col {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 20px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="col">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
  <p>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The column width of 200 was intentional.

Comment: @JasonS if the column width was intentional then using display:inline-block is the right choice.